# "Issue found: Login Credentials" App review in Google Play

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I uploaded a new app in the google play console to review, then I received an email that say:

> App Status: Rejected
> Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to the policy issue(s) listed below. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
> ....
> Issue found: Login Credentials
> In order for us to review your app for compliance with Developer Program policies we will need you to provide valid login credentials for your app, and any other resources needed to review your app.
> ....
> In this case:
> We could not access the in-app content with the login credentials that you have provided.

The problem is that my app does not ask the user for any login information. However, it has an in-app purchase, if that makes a difference. The in-app purchase does not block any pages, but limit the user's ability to select some checkboxs before the upgrade.

It is also woth mentioning that this app has android auto support.

Any ideas how to solve this issue? Thank you.

Tried to contact google play's support, but they repeated the same thing in the email. Also, I added a testing email to the app access section, but it made no difference.